# How to defer resource cleanup when that resource outlives the scope of the surrounding function?

Tags: go, defer-keyword

Let's take the example of [this piece of code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40452289/15261644) that makes the logger write to a local file instead of the standard output:

```golang
f, err := os.OpenFile("filename", os.O_WRONLY|os.O_CREATE|os.O_APPEND, 0644)
if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
}   

defer f.Close()

log.SetOutput(f)
```

The author is putting this code straight into the `main()` function, which makes it work as intended. But if I wanted to put this code into a a dedicated function which `main()` may then call, then it would no longer work, because the `f.Close()` would be called before the logger ever gets used.

E.g. (if the code above is now in a function called `logToFile()`):

```
main() {
   logToFile()
   log.Print("I'm going to end up in stdout\n")
}
```

**Can** this be moved into its own function, and still have it work as intended?

I've had the same situation with opening/closing of a database connection. And it seems like the only way is to do both of these things inside the `main()`, but I think the code would look cleaner and more SoC if we could divide it into functions. Is this a no-no in Go?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You looking for something like this?

```
type closerFunc func() error

func logToFile(path string) closerFunc {
    f, err := os.OpenFile(path, os.O_WRONLY|os.O_CREATE|os.O_APPEND, 0644)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }   

    log.SetOutput(f)

    return func() error {
        return f.Close()
    }
}
```

To use:

```
func main() {
    closerFn := logToFile("filename")
    defer closerFn()

    log.Print("logs to file\n")
}
```

Comment: Small note: as written, you could just `return f.Close` from `logToFile`. But you might want to return a function that first calls `log.SetOutput` to send the output somewhere other than the file that's about to be closed... :-)

Comment: The same principle can be found in the ubiquitous `ctx, cancel := context.WithCancel(ctx); defer cancel()`

Comment: That approach works (and I've used it myself many times), but it is a bit prone to accidentally forgetting to bind the `closerFunc` — it's easy to accidentally write `logToFilename("filename")` where you should have `closerFn := logToFile("filename")`, and hard to spot the dropped argument on the caller side during code review or debugging.

Comment: My assumption from the OP was the log setting was for the duration of the program & the close was to ensure all output was flushed. For temporary destination changes, then yes there are more natural options available.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use [continuation-passing style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation-passing_style), passing the code to be executed within the `defer` block as an explicit argument:

```golang
func withLogToFile(filename string, body func()) {
    f, err := os.OpenFile(filename, os.O_WRONLY|os.O_CREATE|os.O_APPEND, 0644)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    prevOut := log.Writer()
    log.SetOutput(f)
    defer func() {
        log.SetOutput(prevOut)
        if err := f.Close(); err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
    }()

    body()
}
```

Then the call site becomes:

```golang
func main() {
    withLogToFile(filename, func() {
        log.Print("I'm going to end up in ", filename)
    })
}
```

(https://play.golang.org/p/ebCvtzufU5U)

Comment: Interesting idea. Small note: I'd probably record the current log output destination via `log.Writer()` rather than assume it's `os.Stderr`

Comment: Ah, good point! I had overlooked the `log.Writer` function — updated the answer to use it explicitly.