# How to handle `defer` in a function when using intermediary resources

Tags: go

Given the following function

```golang
func jsonBodyReader(config Config, r *http.Request) (io.Reader, error) {
    bodyReader := io.LimitReader(r.Body, config.Reports.Max.Body)
    // defer r.Body.Close()

    gzipReader, err := gzip.NewReader(bodyReader)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    // defer gzipReader.Close()

    return io.LimitReader(gzipReader, config.Reports.Max.Json), nil
}
```

what would be the best way to handle the deferred close of `r.Body` and `gzipReader`?

Is it really necessary to always return all intermediary resources/streams/readers to be able to defer/close them in the parent function?

Another example

```golang
func save(target string, reader io.Reader) (io.Reader, *os.File, error) {
    file, err := os.Create(target)
    if err != nil {
        return reader, nil, err
    }
    /// defer file.Close()

    return io.TeeReader(reader, file), file, nil
}
```

In this case I have to return `os.File` just to be able to call `file.Close()` in the parent.

I found this related question: [How to defer resource cleanup when that resource outlives the scope of the surrounding function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68693616/how-to-defer-resource-cleanup-when-that-resource-outlives-the-scope-of-the-surro) Unfortunately the suggested solutions are still awkward for my use case.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the caller of a function has to read from a file or stream opened or modified by a function, you cannot defer-close it in that function. The stream  or file would be closed when the function returns, failing the caller who will try to read from it.

In your first example, you have two limited readers, one to limit the body, and the other to limit the json unzipped. You can do something like this:

```
func jsonBodyReader(config Config, r *http.Request) (io.ReadCloser, error) {
    bodyReader := io.LimitReader(r.Body, config.Reports.Max.Body)
    gzipReader, err := gzip.NewReader(bodyReader)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return readerCloser{
       Reader:io.LimitReader(gzipReader, config.Reports.Max.Json),
       cl: r.Body,
    }, nil
}
```

where

```
type readerCloser struct {
   io.Reader
   cl io.Closer
}

func (r *readerCloser) Close() error { return r.cl.Close() }
```

The `readerCloser` type allows you to return a `ReaderCloser` that the caller can read from and close, which will close the source stream.